# Suppose $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x \cdot g(x) } =0 $ for every $g(x)>1$. Does this imply that $f(x)=O(x)$.

Tags: limits

Suppose  $f$ is a positive function.  Now suppose that
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x\cdot g(x) } =0 
\end{align}
for every function $g(x)$ that satisfies: the exists $x_0$ such that 
\begin{align}
g(x) >1 ,  x \ge x_0. 
\end{align}

Question:  Can we write the above in terms of Landau notation?  In particular, does the above property imply that $f(x)=O(x)$

Comment: Hint: Suppose $g(x)\equiv 2$, then what does the resulting limit tell you?

Comment: @adfriedman  It tells us that $ \frac{1}{2 }\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: What is the definition of $f(x)=O(x)$ ?

Comment: @HKlee  $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} <\infty$.

Comment: Well, you would have $x$ in the denominator, but that is sufficient to tell you that $f(x) \in O(x)$. Recall that the limit definition of “$f(x)\in O(g(x))$”, i.e.,$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|<\infty$ (which more generally uses the sup limit instead, but here they are equal as the limit exists) is equivalent to the “eventually bounded by some multiple” definition, i.e., there exists some $M>0$ so that $|f(x)|<M|g(x)|$ for all $x$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

In hint of adfriedman, let $g(x)=2$. Hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow
\infty}\ \frac{f(x)}{2x}=0$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\
\frac{f(x)}{x}=0 <\infty$.